# When I insert "'50261111111s11", it inserts 2147483647 instead

Tags: mysql

When I run this:

```
INSERT INTO `orders` (`order_id`) VALUES ('50261111111s11');
```

The following gets inserted:

order_id => **2147483647**

The field order_id is an INT type, so I am assuming that is the root cause. What I do not get is why it converted it to that number. I would normally expect it to insert a 0 since I used an alpha character in there. What gives?

Comment: just answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23550231/long-integer-is-transformed-when-inserted-in-shorter-column-not-truncated-why/23550275#23550275 so not adding a duplicate one.

Comment: That number looks like 2G to me...

Comment: your column `order_id` is not set as a `varchar` column, but rather an `int` column, or some other numerical kind. *Or* you need to use `bigint`.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty - thank you for not adding to the unnecessary duplication of information. I wish other people were equally disciplined.

Comment: Apologizes! Apparently someone beat me to this question by 2 hours!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the string `'50261111111s11'` is [implicitly coerced](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html) to `50261111111`<sup>1</sup>.

Then it is capped at `2147483647`<sup>2</sup>, which is the [maximum value for an INT field](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html) in MySQL.

(Unless an Order ID *is* a constrained integer, such an auto-increment key, maybe it should be a CHAR/VARCHAR column?)

---

<sup>1</sup> See the [INSERT statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html):

> This might involve [an implicit] type conversion if the type of the expression does not match the type of the column, and conversion of a given value can result in different inserted values depending on the data type.

(MySQL might implement a direct conversion/truncation to INT, but consider the case where the value supplied was `CONVERT("50261111111s11", SIGNED INTEGER)` - the result is 50261111111, not 0.)

<sup>2</sup> From [11.2.6 Out-of-Range and Overflow Handling](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/out-of-range-and-overflow.html):

> - If strict SQL mode is enabled, MySQL rejects the out-of-range value with an error, and the insert fails, in accordance with the SQL standard.
> - If no restrictive modes are enabled, *MySQL clips the value to the appropriate endpoint of the range and stores the resulting value instead.*

Answer (score -1):

you are inserting a string ... VALUES ('50261111111**s**11')  in an int field, you should change order_id to varchar

Comment: This doesn't answer the question that was asked.

Comment: lol sorry yes, I was not reading properly at the time...