# Out of range in mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to add integer 12345678901234 in my DB.
Although my value is **INT(15)** but I face with error **'value out of range'**.
Regards if anyone could help me.

Comment: check here I answered here 2 days back http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23550231/long-integer-is-transformed-when-inserted-in-shorter-column-not-truncated-why/23550275#23550275

Comment: The number in parentheses is not the number of digits, but rather the display width of the column.

Answer (score 2):

An int, with MySQL, is stored on 4 bytes, and, as such, can only contain values between -`2147483648` and `2147483647.`

To save 12345678901234 into your DB you need **bigint** type