# Mysql INSERT recording wrong value

Tags: mysql, sql, database, insert

This must be a simple one but got no idea why is this happening.

Under this query:

```
INSERT INTO assist_reg (ar_id,ar_subid,ar_date) VALUES ('','2431052014','2014-05-31');
```

Field ar_subid on DDBB always records this value you can see on this screenshot:

[image: screen]

ar_subid is a INT field with maximum of 20 characters, non-null with no predeterminate valur. this table is under UTF8-generalci.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23550231/long-integer-is-transformed-when-inserted-in-shorter-column-not-truncated-why/23550275#23550275 , I have already answered here and the reason

Comment: If you want me to check just post this on an answer.

Comment: well its going to be a duplicate answer !! I would prefer not to post a duplicate answer !!

Answer (score 1):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html - you are exceeding the int data type's max value. You need a bigint