# Int and BigInt datatype in MySql Database int is storing 2147483647 by default

Tags: mysql

I had a phone number field like `phonenumber int(10)` when I was storing phone numbers to this field using a post form it stores some default value `2147483647` I was wondering how it happens? Later I changed the datatype to `BigInt(10)` and it's storing fine. What was the issue with int?

Comment: Answered few days back about this check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23550231/long-integer-is-transformed-when-inserted-in-shorter-column-not-truncated-why/23550275#23550275

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty Both questions have inspired me to a little bit deeper analysis. See my answer too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26506246/709626

Comment: @bostaf +1 from me nicely explained !!

Answer (score 2):

First point, Phone numbers are usually not best to store as numbers - the international code "00" would get truncated for example.

Second the int max is 2,147,483,647 - Anything above that number will be saved as that number. A work around is use an unsigned int to allow more options (up to 4,294,967,295) so still a number starting with 5 would not be accepted

The best option though is to store in a text based column

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to store phonenumbers as string, not as int!

Comment: any specific reason for this?

Comment: exussum explained it very well