# mysql database does not store complete number of memberId

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Hi Im facing quite an odd problem

Users log in to my website via FB, the member `nr` is quite a lengthy `nr` looking something like this `10153852694717081`.

When user does a transaction im noticing that **only part of the `member_id` gets stored**, the first 8 digits of `member_id`, in the table.

Could this be because the member number is to long? Any other suggestions why this is happening or any fixes that can be applied to work around this problem

Characteristics of `member_nr` row:

```
type=varchar

length = 255
```

Comment: facebook uid's don't have a maximum length, so change your table type to UNSIGNED BIGINT

Comment: would be nice if you can provide a view of your code

Comment: To do this on phpmyadmin do it like this: change column type to bigint and set attributes to unsigned

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23550231/long-integer-is-transformed-when-inserted-in-shorter-column-not-truncated-why/23550275#23550275

Comment: If you are storing it as varchar, there is no need to convert the uid as int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook uid's don't have a set length, therefore there is no way to know how big to set your table so set your column type to an unsigned bigint, how to do this in phpmyadmin is like this: 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

MySQL can only store values up to the max length provided, the rest will be trimmed out. Be sure that your MySQL field have enough space to store the value to avoid truncation.

Answer (score 1):

Is this really a number (in the data type sense)? Sure, it's got digits in it, but it looks to me like this is better stored as a VARCHAR than an INT. If you're not doing arithmetic operations on it, I suggest using VARCHAR. That helps you out with the length limit, just set the VARCHAR length to a sufficient size.