# MySQL: Inserting into Table Confusion

Tags: mysql, insert

I'm not sure if I'm going crazy or what, but this seems like it shouldn't have any issue working but it gives an

> "Out of range value for column 'contxt_id' at row 1" error

Insert Statement:

```
insert into contxt values(34000000000000000000, 'OIG', '110th BCT Frnd/Neut Org', null, 34000000000000000000, 0);
```

Description of Table:

```
mysql> describe contxt;
+-------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field             | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| contxt_id         | int(20)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| cat_code          | varchar(6)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| name_txt          | varchar(80) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| security_clsfc_id | int(20)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| creator_id        | int(20)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| update_seqnr      | int(15)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23550231/long-integer-is-transformed-when-inserted-in-shorter-column-not-truncated-why/23550275#23550275

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The max limit of int is 2147483647. Hence to fix the error, change your datatype to VARCHAR